# Can I use the ADB to see if my application is successfully writing to a text file?

Tags: android, file, adb

My application stores data by writing it to a text file, however when I try to open and read the text file the program doesn't recognize that I've written anything in the text file.

I've decided to try to use the adb to see if I can find the txt file, but when I go to data.app and I try to open my file - com.benbaltes.Android-Fields2.apk it says it can't cd to that app.

Is there anyway I can check and poke around the files in my app? I am rooted and have SU access

Comment: Being root nothing can stop you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you create the text file, but you can definitely poke around. Take a look inside `/data/app-private` or `/data/data/your_package_name/`. You can use `adb shell` to start a shell on the device/emulator, and `cat` works to print a text file (any file, actually) to the console.

The apk file is not where any data is written -- that's the distribution file for your app.